# File to char and char to array C

Tags: c

```
void calcula_estacionamento(){
FILE *f;
int n=0,i=0;
char linha[MAX],hora_i[2]="",min_i[2]="",hora_f[2]="",min_f[2]="";
f=fopen("parque.txt","r");
while(fgets(linha,MAX,f)!=NULL)
{
    while(linha[n]!='h')
    {
        hora_i[i]=linha[n];
        n++;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    n++;
    while(linha[n]!=' ')
    {
        min_i[i]=linha[n];
        n++;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    n++;
    while(linha[n]!='h')
    {
        hora_f[i]=linha[n];
        n++;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    n++;
    while(linha[n]!='\0')
    {
        min_f[i]=linha[n];
        n++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n%s %s %s %s",hora_i,min_i,hora_f,min_f);
    n=0;
    i=0;
}
```

}

In my file "parque.txt", i have a line for example "9h00 12h30"
I want to access that file, get the time, line by line, so I can subtract and know the time passed between one time and the other. The problem is that when I try to pass that from the file to temporary strings (in this case: hora_i="9", min_i="00", hora_f="10", min_f="30") and then I print it what I get is: hora_i="9", min_i="009", hora_f="10009", min_f="3010009". Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, that worked, i never remeber of that to end a string in c, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your program fails is that you are forgetting to add the trailing null to the strings. That brings out the problem that the strings are not long enough. Since you are reading data of unknown length you are also failing to ensure that the incoming string does not overflow the destination array. Those problems exist in each of your loops. Fixing them will violate [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Seriously, it's time to go back to the beginning. Write a single function to read a string to a delimiter, checking against a length, and call that function multiple times. Here is the function signature to get you started.

```
void read_token(char** source, char delimiter, char* destination, int maxlength);
```

Note that the source is a pointer to pointer so you can update it each time. Yes, there are other ways, just pick one and do it.